# How to set the position of X and Y axes in MS chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, mschart, axes

I have set my MS chart look like this :

```
Y axis min = -100 ; max = 100
X axis min = -100 ; max = 100
```

[image: my MS chart now]

But I hope I can set the MS chart Y-axes and X-axes position cross at the center which is **look exactly like this**:

[image: MS chart I want]

Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Axis.Crossing` property. Given your ranges, you'd set

```
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Crossing = 0;
chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Crossing = 0;
```